# error: too few arguments to function 'float getTotalAmount'

Tags: c++, function

Here is the problem i Designed a program to collect blood from users after collecting the data i give them the output. one of the output is retrieved from outside function which is getTotalAmount but i am getting error: too few arguments to function 'float getTotalAmount'. code attached below :

```
class BloodDonator{
private:
          string bloodtype ,name;
          float amount ;
public:
        void set_details(){

                cout<<"Enter Name :";
                cin>>name;
        cout<<"Please select a blood type ...\n";
       cout<<" Enter [1] for A positive\n";
       cout<<" Enter [2] for A negative\n";
       cout<<" Enter [3] for B positive\n";
       cout<<" Enter [4] for B negative\n";
       cout<<" Enter [5] for O positive\n";
        cout<<"Enter [6] for O negative\n";
        cout<<"Enter [7] for AB positive\n";
      cout<<"Enter [8] for AB negative\n";
            cin>>bloodtype;
        cout<<"Enter Amount (ml) :";
        cin>>amount;
        };
        float getAmount(){
        return amount;
        };
        string getName(){
        return name;
        };
        string getBloodType(){
        return bloodtype;
        };
        getTotalAmount(float &amount);
        string n(){return name;}
};
float getTotalAmount(BloodDonator *ps)
{
static float totalamount=0;
totalamount = totalamount + ps->getAmount();
return totalamount;
};
int main()
{
BloodDonator p1 ;
//float getTotalAmount();
//getTotalAmount();

for(int i=0;i<3 ;i++){
            cout<<"         Input Details\n";
            cout<<"------------------------------\n";

        p1.set_details();
        //p1.getTotalAmount(*p1.getAmount());
            cout<<"------------------------------\n";
            cout<<"         output Details\n";
            cout<<"------------------------------\n";

        cout<<"name           :"<<p1.n()<<endl;
        cout<<"blood type     :"<<p1 .getBloodType()<<endl;
        cout<<"Blood Amount   :"<<p1.getAmount()<<endl;
        cout<<"Total Amount of Blood Donated so far :\n"<<getTotalAmount()<<endl;//here is total amount of blood
}
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `getTotalAmount` takes one parameter: BloodDonator*`. You're calling it with o parameters.

Comment: You declare a member function `getTotalAmount(float &amount);` taking a float reference. You later define a general function `float getTotalAmount(BloodDonator *ps)` taking a pointer to `BloodDonator` and then you attempt to use `cout ... <<getTotalAmount()` -- None of those match (or make much sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to change the following segments of your code:

```cpp
// it's ok
cout<<"name           :"<<p1.n()<<endl;

// removed space between "p1." and "getBloodType()"
cout<<"blood type     :"<<p1.getBloodType()<<endl;

// it's ok
cout<<"Blood Amount   :"<<p1.getAmount()<<endl;

// passed pointer to p1, cause getTotalAmount() expects a pointer to BloodDonator object.
cout<<"Total Amount of Blood Donated so far :\n"<<getTotalAmount(&p1)<<endl;
```

Your code has several more problems like:

1. What is the job of `getTotalAmount(float &amount);` inside `BloodDonator` class.
2. if `BloodDonator` has already `getTotalAmount(float &amount);`, then, why there is a `float getTotalAmount(BloodDonator *ps)` doing outside...
3. you're hardcoding blood donars detials, you should inject details through `constructor`...
   etc...

Answer (score 1):

Look at the declaration in the class:

```
getTotalAmount(float &amount);
```

And the call in `main()` (last `cout` statement):

```
getTotalAmount();
```

You need to pass a required pointer variable `p1` (since that's relevant and compatible) to the `getTotalAmount()`.

---

Also the explicit type is missing in the declaration, it defaults to `int`, beware of that. To prevent it, declare it correctly:

```
float getTotalAmount(float &amount);
```

---

Another problem, which is the definition of function. You've just declared a function `getTotalAmount` (non class member function), you actually didn't wrote definition of the class member function `getTotalAmount`, i.e. you've defined the same named functions in two places.

It's up to you to code only for the one required by you and delete the another. In the current code provided by you, the class member function `getTotalAmount` has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems but the fundamental issue is bad program design. Any time you use a static variable you should think hard whether you really need it. Especially as a beginner you will almost never really need to use static variables.

In your code you have a static variable inside `getTotalAmount`. Instead this variable should be in `main` (and non-static). And the calculation to add the total blood donated should also be in `main`. Like this

```
int main()
{
    BloodDonator p1;
    float totalAmount = 0.0f;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
       ...
       cout << "Blood Amount   :" << p1.getAmount() << endl;
       totalAmount = totalAmount + p1.getAmount(); //here is total amount of blood
       cout << "Total Amount of Blood Donated so far :\n" << totalAmount << endl; 
    }
```

The function `getTotalAmount` can be deleted.